# empty response on model using union

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have the following code

```
public function findAccessible(Query $query, array $options){
    return $this->findPublic($query, $options)
                ->union($this->findMyAdmin($query, $options));
}

public function findPublic(Query $query, array $options){
    return $query
            ->where(['public' => true]);
}   

public function findMyAdmin(Query $query, array $options){
    return $query
            ->where(['admin_user_id' => $options['User.id']]);
}
```

The findAccessible call gives me this error message in Chrome: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
No other error message, no entry in error log. I am sure that is because of the union call. How to do it?

**What I want to achieve:**
groups hasAndBelongsTo users
groups: id, name, admin_user_id, public

I would like to get groups

1) what are public groups (This is ok, findPublic method)

2) where admin_user is the given user (This is ok, findMyAdmin method)

3) in where the given user is a member (This is ok, I could do it with an other find()->matching call)

**4) which are accessible for the user**, eg. public OR the given user is admin OR a member - meaning the union of 1), 2) and 3) - that is with what I am struggling. If I put all these to one find method I can not define OR relationship for the membership, as that is done by matching what is translated into an inner join.

Comment: Sounds like PHP or the server died, looking at your code it seems that you are unionizing a query with itself, I could imagine that this creates an endless loop somewhere. It would be helpful if you'd describe what query exactly you are trying to build.

Comment: @ndm Thank you. I agree that should be an endless loop. Please check the update in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really ugly but working solution.

```
public function findAccessible(Query $query, array $options){
    $qq = $this->query($query);
    $memberships = $qq->matching('Users', function($q) use ($options){
                return $q->where(['Users.id' => $options['User.id']]);
                });
    foreach($memberships as $m){
        $memberInGroup[] = $m->id;
    }

    return $query
            ->where(['public' => true])
            ->orWhere(['admin_user_id' => $options['User.id']])
            ->orWhere(['Groups.id IN' => $memberInGroup]);
}
```

I hope somebody will find a better solution and post here.